# TeamViewer remote reboot and logon in Windows user

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

I am trying to remotely reboot the computer to which I am connected to but there is a problem, this computer has an account set (with a username but no password) to which I am connected (among two other  existent accounts to this computer).

I am wondering if I can use TeamViewer remote reboot and before that set automatic Windows logon so the machine will reboot and login to this specific account having the TeamViewer starting each time Windows starts. Will this trick give me access to the remote computer again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just did this two days ago, put TeamViewer into the Startup folder for that user. Open up netplwiz, select the user you want to login, uncheck "Users Must Enter A User Name And Password To Use This Computer". If there is a password to the user normally put that into the Automatic Logon Dialog Box and you should be good to go.

I am not sure if this works if there are multiple users on the computer or if it is a domain computer though so be careful if that is the case.

Comment: yes there are three accounts (it is a conventional PC with internet access), but I want to use only one (which is not the admin account)

Comment: According to this page: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/377-log-automatically-startup.html there should be no problems, but you have to do these changes from an Administrator account. If you don't have access to that one you can't get the automatic logon to work.

Comment: cant I get admin access from the account I am currently logged in? from command line?

Comment: I guess the easiest thing would be to right click cmd and choose "Run as Administrator", that will ask for the administrator password.

Comment: Sorry, I meant right click netplwiz.

Comment: of note: while this method generally works It makes BOTH systems more insecure short of local client side multiple factor auth (POST remote session bind)

Comment: I did the netplwiz but I get a message that I have to log off in order to apply the changes so if I log off how can I log on again? Should I restart instead?

Comment: remote reboot->log off?